# for loop is taking too much time and causes page crach

Tags: javascript, excel

I am manipulating Excel files using javascript, I am converting the file into a json object then looping for each row .
I am using this code

```
document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener("click", () => {
    XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, 'out.xlsx');
    if (selectedfile && etat == 0) {   
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedfile);
        fileReader.onload = (event) => {
            etat++;
            let data = event.target.result;
            let workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" });
            console.log(workbook);
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet],{raw: false});
                let ok = JSON.stringify(rowObject, undefined, 4);
                let tab = JSON.parse(ok);
                let num = tab.length;
                console.log(parseInt(num/1000));
                for(j = 0;j<parseInt(num/1000)+1;j++){
                    let row = j *1000;
                    let ligne;
                    if(j == num)
                    ligne = num;
                    else
                    ligne = (j+1)* 1000;
                   let table = [];
for(i = row; i<ligne; i++){
    let jour = tab[i].JOUR;
    let date = tab[i].DATE;
    let compte = tab[i].COMPTE;
    let code = tab[i].CODE;
    let libelles = tab[i].LIBELLES;
    let debit = tab[i].DEBIT ;
    let creadit = tab[i].CREDIT;
    let ech = tab[i].ECH;
    let LETT = tab[i].LETT;
    table.push( [jour , date,compte , code , libelles , debit , creadit , ech , LETT] );
    console.log(i);
}
                }
                /**/
            });
        }
    }
}
);
```

The excel file contains more than 17k rows, this code takes too much time ( over 15 mins ) and causes crashes.

Comment: what happens if you change the `let ok = JSON.stringify(rowObject, undefined, 4); let tab = JSON.parse(ok);` to just `let tab = rowObject;`? or do you use `ok` somewhere?

Comment: but it may just be the `// code` that's the issue

Comment: comment the codes half by half (like binary search) to locate which part make it slow.

Comment: You could probably get Excel to create the JSON for you in a new sheet, and then you could just access that instead of doing this with JS. It might not be quite the same but I found this easy to do [with Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/108w3fkpe7iUstAmmoObg_GQD1TE-69y-e0vgeD9xysY/edit?usp=sharing) for example. But with 17K of rows maybe a database is now in order.

Comment: put big chunks of code **in the quetsion** so it is readable - does removing the `console.log` help at all - 17k console.log's can slow things

Comment: `table.push([......]).draw(true)` ? arrays have a `draw` method?

Comment: by the way `if(j == num)` will never be true, since j is at most num/1000, so you'll always set `ligne = (j+1)* 1000;` which means you'll be processing up to an extra 999 (empty) rows ...

Comment: i Have updated the code in the question section , Initially it was adding to a datatable , then I changed the code to just fill a table ( I just forget to remove the draw )

Comment: does removing `console.log` in that loop improve anything - I've found console.log in some environments to be a handbrake on performance - also try `for(let i = row; i<ligne; i++)` again, in some environments, global variable access is **slow**

Comment: so, you create `table` ... push a bunch of stuff to it ... then discard it - so, your code basically does nothing

Comment: @Bravo that is the point ,  I am not yet calculating the additionnal columns . For each row   I need to find all rows having the same " CODE " then calculating the average date and add the result to a new column ,  the problem is that just reading the values of the rows is taking that much time

Comment: Dont do the let first and then the table.push with the var, do it directly table.push[ tab[i].JOUR, ...etc. Remove the console.log(i), or change ti to just every 100.

Comment: @Iceman2104, How many columns for one row?